# Запятая: "В другом случае..."

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в предложении: "В другом случае(,) не стоит этого делать"?

Или так: "В идеальном случае(,) нужно посетить все 3 экспозиции".

Благодарю!